# Why some C API doesn't follow Encapsulation

Tags: c, oop

For example, if I need to get files in a directory,

Encapsulation:

```
struct dirent *ent;
ent = readdir (dir);
char *filename = d_name(ent);
```

C:

```
struct dirent *ent;
ent = readdir (dir);
char *filename = ent->d_name;
```

Comment: There is no reason you cannot have a function `d_name` that returns the filename.

Comment: the struct fields can be accessed directly so people will do that. But you could create a macro (with some other name) or a function to perform that encapsulation.

Comment: also, the `ent` data is probably a copy of internal state, so it's already encapsulated, in a structure

Comment: Why would a C API, which predates the very notion of OOP, follow its tenets?

Comment: Having a getter instead of a direct field access is not automatically implying encapsulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following two API variants:

```
struct point get_location(const foo *f)
{
    struct point p;
    p.x = f->something_x;
    p.y = f->something_y;
    return p;
}
```

versus:

```
double get_location_x(const foo *f)
{
    return f->something_x;
}
double get_location_y(const foo *f)
{
    return f->something_y;
}
```

I claim there is nothing "more encapsulated" about the latter than the former.  It's just a matter of perspective whether you consider the result type of the former to be a value type. Likewise, `struct dirent` is a value type whose definition is well-specified and stable/fixed. As @Jean-FrançoisFabre51 commented, it is the result value that's obtained from some internal state encapsulated in the `DIR` object.

Comment: It will get more encapsulated if we use opaque pointers *a la* `FILE`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `DIR` is analogous to `FILE`. `struct dirent` is analogous to the data you read out of a file with `fread`.

Comment: In my perspective,  both "struct dirent" and "struct point" in your example is a class type rather a primitive type/value type. Even though it is simple and well-specified. Could you justify your perspective?

Comment: One justify I can think of is that the `struct dirent` is immutable, which make method unnecessary. Still, I don't know how to justify `struct point`.

Comment: On a given platform, `struct dirent` is stable, but POSIX only defines two members — `d_ino` and `d_name` — but some implementations provide extra fields (`d_namlen`, maybe `d_type`, maybe others).